# GXT ContentPanel's header align to the right

Tags: gxt

I'm using gxt to my application.
I won't to align the ContentPanel's header ToolButtons to the left instaed to the right (which is the defualt)
there is no method such as setHorizontalAlogment.
any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any method offered by GXT to achieve this. But I found a way to do this. Here is the code that demonstrates how you can achieve this.

```
public class CustomPanel extends ContentPanel {
  public CustomPanel() {
    super();
    addListener(Events.Render, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(final BaseEvent be) {
            final HorizontalPanel panel = getWidgetPanel(getHeader());
            panel.setStyleAttribute("float", "left");
        }
    });
  }

      //widgetPanel is private. It can be accessed using JSNI
  private native HorizontalPanel getWidgetPanel(Component header)/*-{
        return header.@com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Header::widgetPanel;

  }-*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set the position through the style .. float: left